# Loading assets in just_audiio

Tags: flutter, just-audio

When trying to load an asset in just_audio with an empty space in asset name I get an error:
**An error occured Unable to load asset: audio/book/John%20William.mp3**,
Is white space not allowed in asset names or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug.

When you click on the button to submit a bug on GitHub, the first question is a qualifying question - if you can answer it, then it qualifies as a bug:

> Which API doesn't behave as documented, and how does it misbehave?

When filling in your bug report, you can answer this qualifying question as follows:

> [This documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/just_audio/latest/just_audio/AudioPlayer/setAsset.html) suggests that I can load an asset from any valid asset path, but it gives an error if the asset path contains a space. The documentation does not say say anything about spaces not being allowed. It seems the space is converted to `%20` which may be causing the issue.

This looks like a simple bug, so if you are able to submit a bug report as per the GitHub instructions, it will probably be fixed quickly.

(Update: The bug was since reported on GitHub and fixed in version 0.6.15)